# Django Selenium Test, create a user and check logged in

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium

I'm trying to test that a user can login and view their account dashboard with selenium.

I create the user in the setUp() function but when I try and login, the login fails. It seems the user is not being created. (although when i add a breakpoint in the setUp..it is)

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        # create user
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=USERNAME,
                                             email=None,
                                             password=PASSWORD)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        User.objects.all().delete()

    def test_login(self):
        self.driver.get(BASE_URL + '/accounts/login/?next=/dashboard')

        username = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.width-half.right #id_username')
        username.send_keys(USERNAME)

        password = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.width-half.right #id_password')
        password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

        btn_login = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '.width-half.right .actions button')
        # Login
        btn_login.click()

        # Check on the user dashboard
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dash-left')))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does your test fail? If you look at the Firefox instance that Selenium spawns, do you see the expected fields getting filled, and the button being clicked?

Comment: @Louis the login failed html is showing on the page itself, the button gets clicked and the POST happens.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you describe happening, here is what I think is going on. Your `BASE_URL` is set to connect to your *development* server which you've started with `./manage.py runserver`. (It can't be connecting to a test server started by `TestCase` because `TestCase` does not start a server, but it connects to *something*, which must be your development server.) So Selenium does get a login page because there is a server responding. However, when you try to login, it fails because the user you created is created in the *test* database created for testing, and not in the *development* one.

The solution is twofold:

1. Base you test case on `django.test.LiveServerTestCase` like migonzalvar suggested so that a test server is started.
2. Set your `BASE_URL` to connect to this server. The default address is `localhost:8081`. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase) if you need to change the address.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `LiveServerTestCase` instead of `TestCase`. It's the way recommended by [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class MyTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
...
```

Also, although not related with your problem, you don't need to execute `User.objects.all().delete()` in the `tearDown` method. The database is deleted after every test.

Comment: Same result using that. I tried a breakpoint within the test function, the user 100% is in the database then. Very strange.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help you.